# How to get a list of constants from Locale class of Flutter?

Tags: flutter, locale

I have an application who use locale to choose the language and a json with translations and I am making a configurator. For it, I need to have a list of locale in the format `language_COUNTRYNAME` like `en_US`.

I have found [this list of constants](https://pub.dev/documentation/locales/latest/locales/Locale-class.html#constants) in Locale flutter class and I want to get the complete list in JSON without copy it manually, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

I have do finally with the manual way.

Here the list:

```json
{
  "af_NA": "Afrikaans Namibia",
  "af_ZA": "Afrikaans South Africa",
  "agq_CM": "Aghem Cameroon",
  "ak_GH": "Akan Ghana",
  "am_ET": "Amharic Ethiopia",
  "ar_001": "Arabic World",
  "ar_AE": "Arabic United Arab Emirates",
  "ar_BH": "Arabic Bahrain",
  "ar_DJ": "Arabic Djibouti",
  "ar_DZ": "Arabic Algeria",
  "ar_EG": "Arabic Egypt",
  "ar_EH": "Arabic Western Sahara",
  "ar_ER": "Arabic Eritrea",
  "ar_IL": "Arabic Israel",
  "ar_IQ": "Arabic Iraq",
  "ar_JO": "Arabic Jordan",
  "ar_KM": "Arabic Comoros",
  "ar_KW": "Arabic Kuwait",
  "ar_LB": "Arabic Lebanon",
  "ar_LY": "Arabic Libya",
  "ar_MA": "Arabic Morocco",
  "ar_MR": "Arabic Mauritania",
  "ar_OM": "Arabic Oman",
  "ar_PS": "Arabic Palestine",
  "ar_QA": "Arabic Qatar",
  "ar_SA": "Arabic Saudi Arabia",
  "ar_SD": "Arabic Sudan",
  "ar_SO": "Arabic Somalia",
  "ar_SS": "Arabic South Sudan",
  "ar_SY": "Arabic Syria",
  "ar_TD": "Arabic Chad",
  "ar_TN": "Arabic Tunisia",
  "ar_YE": "Arabic Yemen",
  "as_IN": "Assamese India",
  "asa_TZ": "Asu Tanzania",
  "az_AZ": "Azerbaijan",
  "bas_CM": "Basaa Cameroon",
  "be_BY": "Belarusian Belarus",
  "bem_ZM": "Bemba Zambia",
  "bez_TZ": "Bena Tanzania",
  "bg_BG": "Bulgarian Bulgaria",
  "bm_ML": "Bambara Mali",
  "bn_BD": "Bengali Bangladesh",
  "bn_IN": "Bengali India",
  "bo_CN": "Tibetan China",
  "bo_IN": "Tibetan India",
  "br_FR": "Breton France",
  "brx_IN": "Bodo India",
  "bs_BA": "Bosnian Bosnia Herzegovina (Cyrillic/Latin)",
  "ca_AD": "Catalan Andorra",
  "ca_ES": "Catalan Spain",
  "ca_FR": "Catalan France",
  "ca_IT": "Catalan Italy",
  "cgg_UG": "Chiga Uganda",
  "chr_US": "Cherokee United States",
  "cs_CZ": "Czech Czech Republic",
  "cy_GB": "Welsh United Kingdom",
  "da_DK": "Danish Denmark",
  "da_GL": "Danish Greenland",
  "dav_KE": "Taita Kenya",
  "de_AT": "German Austria",
  "de_BE": "German Belgium",
  "de_CH": "German Switzerland",
  "de_DE": "German Germany",
  "de_LI": "German Liechtenstein",
  "de_LU": "German Luxembourg",
  "dje_NE": "Zarma Niger",
  "dua_CM": "Duala Cameroon",
  "dyo_SN": "Jola Fonyi Senegal",
  "dz_BT": "Dzongkha Bhutan",
  "ebu_KE": "Embu Kenya",
  "ee_GH": "Ewe Ghana",
  "ee_TG": "Ewe Togo",
  "el_CY": "Greek Cyprus",
  "el_GR": "Greek Greece",
  "en_001": "English World",
  "en_150": "English Europe",
  "en_AG": "English Antigua Barbuda",
  "en_AI": "English Anguilla",
  "en_AS": "English American Samoa",
  "en_AU": "English Australia",
  "en_BB": "English Barbados",
  "en_BE": "English Belgium",
  "en_BM": "English Bermuda",
  "en_BS": "English Bahamas",
  "en_BW": "English Botswana",
  "en_BZ": "English Belize",
  "en_CA": "English Canada",
  "en_CC": "English Cocos Keeling Islands",
  "en_CK": "English Cook Islands",
  "en_CM": "English Cameroon",
  "en_CX": "English Christmas Island",
  "en_DG": "English Diego Garcia",
  "en_DM": "English Dominica",
  "en_ER": "English Eritrea",
  "en_FJ": "English Fiji",
  "en_FK": "English Falkland Islands Islas Malvinas",
  "en_FM": "English Micronesia",
  "en_GB": "English United Kingdom",
  "en_GD": "English Grenada",
  "en_GG": "English Guernsey",
  "en_GH": "English Ghana",
  "en_GI": "English Gibraltar",
  "en_GM": "English Gambia",
  "en_GU": "English Guam",
  "en_GY": "English Guyana",
  "en_HK": "English Hong Kong",
  "en_IE": "English Ireland",
  "en_IM": "English Isle Of Man",
  "en_IN": "English India",
  "en_IO": "English British Indian Ocean Territory",
  "en_JE": "English Jersey",
  "en_JM": "English Jamaica",
  "en_KE": "English Kenya",
  "en_KI": "English Kiribati",
  "en_KN": "English Saint Kitts Nevis",
  "en_KY": "English Cayman Islands",
  "en_LC": "English Saint Lucia",
  "en_LR": "English Liberia",
  "en_LS": "English Lesotho",
  "en_MG": "English Madagascar",
  "en_MH": "English Marshall Islands",
  "en_MO": "English Macau",
  "en_MP": "English Northern Mariana Islands",
  "en_MS": "English Montserrat",
  "en_MT": "English Malta",
  "en_MU": "English Mauritius",
  "en_MW": "English Malawi",
  "en_NA": "English Namibia",
  "en_NF": "English Norfolk Island",
  "en_NG": "English Nigeria",
  "en_NR": "English Nauru",
  "en_NU": "English Niue",
  "en_NZ": "English New Zealand",
  "en_PG": "English Papua New Guinea",
  "en_PH": "English Philippines",
  "en_PK": "English Pakistan",
  "en_PN": "English Pitcairn Islands",
  "en_PR": "English Puerto Rico",
  "en_PW": "English Palau",
  "en_RW": "English Rwanda",
  "en_SB": "English Solomon Islands",
  "en_SC": "English Seychelles",
  "en_SD": "English Sudan",
  "en_SG": "English Singapore",
  "en_SH": "English Saint Helena",
  "en_SL": "English Sierra Leone",
  "en_SS": "English South Sudan",
  "en_SX": "English Sint Maarten",
  "en_SZ": "English Swaziland",
  "en_TC": "English Turks Caicos Islands",
  "en_TK": "English Tokelau",
  "en_TO": "English Tonga",
  "en_TT": "English Trinidad Tobago",
  "en_TV": "English Tuvalu",
  "en_TZ": "English Tanzania",
  "en_UG": "English Uganda",
  "en_UM": "English Us Outlying Islands",
  "en_US": "English United States",
  "en_VC": "English St Vincent Grenadines",
  "en_VG": "English British Virgin Islands",
  "en_VI": "English Us Virgin Islands",
  "en_VU": "English Vanuatu",
  "en_WS": "English Samoa",
  "en_ZA": "English South Africa",
  "en_ZM": "English Zambia",
  "en_ZW": "English Zimbabwe",
  "es_419": "Spanish Latin America",
  "es_AR": "Spanish Argentina",
  "es_BO": "Spanish Bolivia",
  "es_CL": "Spanish Chile",
  "es_CO": "Spanish Colombia",
  "es_CR": "Spanish Costa Rica",
  "es_CU": "Spanish Cuba",
  "es_DO": "Spanish Dominican Republic",
  "es_EA": "Spanish Ceuta Melilla",
  "es_EC": "Spanish Ecuador",
  "es_ES": "Spanish Spain",
  "es_GQ": "Spanish Equatorial Guinea",
  "es_GT": "Spanish Guatemala",
  "es_HN": "Spanish Honduras",
  "es_IC": "Spanish Canary Islands",
  "es_MX": "Spanish Mexico",
  "es_NI": "Spanish Nicaragua",
  "es_PA": "Spanish Panama",
  "es_PE": "Spanish Peru",
  "es_PH": "Spanish Philippines",
  "es_PR": "Spanish Puerto Rico",
  "es_PY": "Spanish Paraguay",
  "es_SV": "Spanish El Salvador",
  "es_US": "Spanish United States",
  "es_UY": "Spanish Uruguay",
  "es_VE": "Spanish Venezuela",
  "et_EE": "Estonian Estonia",
  "eu_ES": "Basque Spain",
  "ewo_CM": "Ewondo Cameroon",
  "fa_AF": "Persian Afghanistan",
  "fa_IR": "Persian Iran",
  "ff_SN": "Fulah Senegal",
  "fi_FI": "Finnish Finland",
  "fil_PH": "Filipino Philippines",
  "fo_FO": "Faroese Faroe Islands",
  "fr_BE": "French Belgium",
  "fr_BF": "French Burkina Faso",
  "fr_BI": "French Burundi",
  "fr_BJ": "French Benin",
  "fr_BL": "French Saint Bartelemy",
  "fr_CA": "French Canada",
  "fr_CD": "French Congo Drc",
  "fr_CF": "French Central African Republic",
  "fr_CG": "French Congo Republic",
  "fr_CH": "French Switzerland",
  "fr_CI": "French Cote D Ivoire",
  "fr_CM": "French Cameroon",
  "fr_DJ": "French Djibouti",
  "fr_DZ": "French Algeria",
  "fr_FR": "French France",
  "fr_GA": "French Gabon",
  "fr_GF": "French French Guiana",
  "fr_GN": "French Guinea",
  "fr_GP": "French Guadeloupe",
  "fr_GQ": "French Equatorial Guinea",
  "fr_HT": "French Haiti",
  "fr_KM": "French Comoros",
  "fr_LU": "French Luxembourg",
  "fr_MA": "French Morocco",
  "fr_MC": "French Monaco",
  "fr_MF": "French Saint Martin",
  "fr_MG": "French Madagascar",
  "fr_ML": "French Mali",
  "fr_MQ": "French Martinique",
  "fr_MR": "French Mauritania",
  "fr_MU": "French Mauritius",
  "fr_NC": "French New Caledonia",
  "fr_NE": "French Niger",
  "fr_PF": "French French Polynesia",
  "fr_PM": "French Saint Pierre Miquelon",
  "fr_RE": "French Reunion",
  "fr_RW": "French Rwanda",
  "fr_SC": "French Seychelles",
  "fr_SN": "French Senegal",
  "fr_SY": "French Syria",
  "fr_TD": "French Chad",
  "fr_TG": "French Togo",
  "fr_TN": "French Tunisia",
  "fr_VU": "French Vanuatu",
  "fr_WF": "French Wallis Futuna",
  "fr_YT": "French Mayotte",
  "ga_IE": "Irish Ireland",
  "gl_ES": "Galician Spain",
  "gsw_CH": "Swiss German Switzerland",
  "gsw_LI": "Swiss German Liechtenstein",
  "gu_IN": "Gujarati India",
  "guz_KE": "Gusii Kenya",
  "gv_IM": "Manx Isle Of Man",
  "ha_GH": "Hausa Latin Ghana",
  "ha_NE": "Hausa Latin Niger",
  "ha_NG": "Hausa Latin Nigeria",
  "haw_US": "Hawaiian United States",
  "hi_IN": "Hindi India",
  "hr_BA": "Croatian Bosnia Herzegovina",
  "hr_HR": "Croatian Croatia",
  "hu_HU": "Hungarian Hungary",
  "hy_AM": "Armenian Armenia",
  "ig_NG": "Igbo Nigeria",
  "ii_CN": "Sichuan Yi China",
  "in_ID": "Indonesian Indonesia",
  "is_IS": "Icelandic Iceland",
  "it_CH": "Italian Switzerland",
  "it_IT": "Italian Italy",
  "it_SM": "Italian San Marino",
  "iw_IL": "Hebrew Israel",
  "ja_JP": "Japanese Japan",
  "jgo_CM": "Ngomba Cameroon",
  "jmc_TZ": "Machame Tanzania",
  "ka_GE": "Georgian Georgia",
  "kab_DZ": "Kabyle Algeria",
  "kam_KE": "Kamba Kenya",
  "kde_TZ": "Makonde Tanzania",
  "kea_CV": "Kabuverdianu Cape Verde",
  "khq_ML": "Koyra Chiini Mali",
  "ki_KE": "Kikuyu Kenya",
  "kk_KZ": "Kazakh Cyrillic Kazakhstan",
  "kkj_CM": "Kako Cameroon",
  "kl_GL": "Kalaallisut Greenland",
  "kln_KE": "Kalenjin Kenya",
  "km_KH": "Khmer Cambodia",
  "kn_IN": "Kannada India",
  "ko_KP": "Korean North Korea",
  "ko_KR": "Korean South Korea",
  "kok_IN": "Konkani India",
  "ks_IN": "Kashmiri Arabic India",
  "ksb_TZ": "Shambala Tanzania",
  "ksf_CM": "Bafia Cameroon",
  "kw_GB": "Cornish United Kingdom",
  "ky_KG": "Kyrgyz Cyrillic Kyrgyzstan",
  "lag_TZ": "Langi Tanzania",
  "lg_UG": "Ganda Uganda",
  "lkt_US": "Lakota United States",
  "ln_AO": "Lingala Angola",
  "ln_CD": "Lingala Congo Drc",
  "ln_CF": "Lingala Central African Republic",
  "ln_CG": "Lingala Congo Republic",
  "lo_LA": "Lao Laos",
  "lt_LT": "Lithuanian Lithuania",
  "lu_CD": "Luba Katanga Congo Drc",
  "luo_KE": "Luo Kenya",
  "luy_KE": "Luyia Kenya",
  "lv_LV": "Latvian Latvia",
  "mas_KE": "Masai Kenya",
  "mas_TZ": "Masai Tanzania",
  "mer_KE": "Meru Kenya",
  "mfe_MU": "Morisyen Mauritius",
  "mg_MG": "Malagasy Madagascar",
  "mgh_MZ": "Makhuwa Meetto Mozambique",
  "mgo_CM": "Meta Cameroon",
  "mk_MK": "Macedonian Macedonia Fyrom",
  "ml_IN": "Malayalam India",
  "mn_MN": "Mongolian Cyrillic Mongolia",
  "mr_IN": "Marathi India",
  "ms_BN": "Malay Latin Brunei",
  "ms_MY": "Malay Latin Malaysia",
  "ms_SG": "Malay Latin Singapore",
  "mt_MT": "Maltese Malta",
  "mua_CM": "Mundang Cameroon",
  "my_MM": "Burmese Myanmar Burma",
  "naq_NA": "Nama Namibia",
  "nb_NO": "Norwegian Bokmal Norway",
  "nb_SJ": "Norwegian Bokmal Svalbard Jan Mayen",
  "nd_ZW": "North Ndebele Zimbabwe",
  "ne_IN": "Nepali India",
  "ne_NP": "Nepali Nepal",
  "nl_AW": "Dutch Aruba",
  "nl_BE": "Dutch Belgium",
  "nl_BQ": "Dutch Caribbean Netherlands",
  "nl_CW": "Dutch Curacao",
  "nl_NL": "Dutch Netherlands",
  "nl_SR": "Dutch Suriname",
  "nl_SX": "Dutch Sint Maarten",
  "nmg_CM": "Kwasio Cameroon",
  "nn_NO": "Norwegian Nynorsk Norway",
  "nnh_CM": "Ngiemboon Cameroon",
  "nus_SD": "Nuer Sudan",
  "nyn_UG": "Nyankole Uganda",
  "om_ET": "Oromo Ethiopia",
  "om_KE": "Oromo Kenya",
  "or_IN": "Oriya India",
  "pa_IN": "Punjabi Gurmukhi India",
  "pa_PK": "Punjabi Arabic Pakistan",
  "pl_PL": "Polish Poland",
  "ps_AF": "Pashto Afghanistan",
  "pt_AO": "Portuguese Angola",
  "pt_BR": "Portuguese Brazil",
  "pt_CV": "Portuguese Cape Verde",
  "pt_GW": "Portuguese Guinea Bissau",
  "pt_MO": "Portuguese Macau",
  "pt_MZ": "Portuguese Mozambique",
  "pt_PT": "Portuguese Portugal",
  "pt_ST": "Portuguese Sao Tome Principe",
  "pt_TL": "Portuguese Timor Leste",
  "rm_CH": "Romansh Switzerland",
  "rn_BI": "Rundi Burundi",
  "ro_MD": "Romanian Moldova",
  "ro_RO": "Romanian Romania",
  "rof_TZ": "Rombo Tanzania",
  "ru_BY": "Russian Belarus",
  "ru_KG": "Russian Kyrgyzstan",
  "ru_KZ": "Russian Kazakhstan",
  "ru_MD": "Russian Moldova",
  "ru_RU": "Russian Russia",
  "ru_UA": "Russian Ukraine",
  "rw_RW": "Kinyarwanda Rwanda",
  "rwk_TZ": "Rwa Tanzania",
  "saq_KE": "Samburu Kenya",
  "sbp_TZ": "Sangu Tanzania",
  "seh_MZ": "Sena Mozambique",
  "ses_ML": "Koyraboro Senni Mali",
  "sg_CF": "Sango Central African Republic",
  "shi_MA": "Tachelhit Morocco (Tifinagh/Latin)",
  "si_LK": "Sinhala Sri Lanka",
  "sk_SK": "Slovak Slovakia",
  "sl_SI": "Slovenian Slovenia",
  "sn_ZW": "Shona Zimbabwe",
  "so_DJ": "Somali Djibouti",
  "so_ET": "Somali Ethiopia",
  "so_KE": "Somali Kenya",
  "so_SO": "Somali Somalia",
  "sq_AL": "Albanian Albania",
  "sq_MK": "Albanian Macedonia Fyrom",
  "sq_XK": "Albanian Kosovo",
  "sr_BA": "Serbian Bosnia Herzegovina (Cyrillic/Latin)",
  "sr_ME": "Serbian Montenegro (Cyrillic/Latin)",
  "sr_RS": "Serbian Serbia (Cyrillic/Latin)",
  "sr_XK": "Serbian Kosovo (Cyrillic/Latin)",
  "sv_AX": "Swedish Aland Islands",
  "sv_FI": "Swedish Finland",
  "sv_SE": "Swedish Sweden",
  "sw_KE": "Swahili Kenya",
  "sw_TZ": "Swahili Tanzania",
  "sw_UG": "Swahili Uganda",
  "swc_CD": "Congo Swahili Congo Drc",
  "ta_IN": "Tamil India",
  "ta_LK": "Tamil Sri Lanka",
  "ta_MY": "Tamil Malaysia",
  "ta_SG": "Tamil Singapore",
  "te_IN": "Telugu India",
  "teo_KE": "Teso Kenya",
  "teo_UG": "Teso Uganda",
  "th_TH": "Thai Thailand",
  "ti_ER": "Tigrinya Eritrea",
  "ti_ET": "Tigrinya Ethiopia",
  "to_TO": "Tongan Tonga",
  "tr_CY": "Turkish Cyprus",
  "tr_TR": "Turkish Turkey",
  "twq_NE": "Tasawaq Niger",
  "tzm_MA": "Central Atlas Tamazight Latin Morocco",
  "ug_CN": "Uyghur Arabic China",
  "uk_UA": "Ukrainian Ukraine",
  "ur_IN": "Urdu India",
  "ur_PK": "Urdu Pakistan",
  "uz_AF": "Uzbek Arabic Afghanistan",
  "uz_UZ": "Uzbek Uzbekistan (Cyrillic/Latin)",
  "vai_LR": "Vai Latin Liberia (Vai/Latin)",
  "vi_VN": "Vietnamese Vietnam",
  "vun_TZ": "Vunjo Tanzania",
  "xog_UG": "Soga Uganda",
  "yav_CM": "Yangben Cameroon",
  "yo_BJ": "Yoruba Benin",
  "yo_NG": "Yoruba Nigeria",
  "zgh_MA": "Standard Moroccan Tamazight Morocco",
  "zh_CN": "Chinese Simplified Han China",
  "zh_HK": "Chinese Han Hong Kong (Simplified+Traditional)",
  "zh_MO": "Chinese Han Macau (Simplified+Traditional)",
  "zh_SG": "Chinese Simplified Han Singapore",
  "zh_TW": "Chinese Traditional Han Taiwan",
  "zu_ZA": "Zulu South Africa"
}
```